# firebase.auth() Shows an error in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to develop an app with Authentication using Firebase with TypeScript but found an error when calling the .auth function.

The error that's showing is upon hover is:

> Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("e:/Projects/spectrum-test/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.ts(2339)
> any

This line ( `export const auth = firebase.auth();` )will work fine in JS but for some reason TS doesn't like it;

**firebase.ts**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

I've already installed `@firebase/auth-types@0.11.0` but it does not resolve the issue

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of the Firebase Authentication SDK are you using? Can you show the dependency you added for that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm using the following firebase dependencies below:

"firebase": "^9.0.1",
"firebase-admin": "^9.11.1",
"firebase-functions": "^3.15.5",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For version 9.0 and above of the JavaScript SDK, Firebase has switched over to using a modular/functional syntax. If you want to continue using the previous syntax, you'll have to import the libraries from the `compat` path as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat):

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed the above and with the full implementation it worked

```
 import config from "./config"// this is the default firebase configuration
 import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
 import "firebase/compat/auth"
 import "firebase/compat/firestore"

 const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)

 const auth = firebaseApp.auth()
 const db = firebaseApp.firestore()

 export default Object.freeze({ auth, db })
 export { auth, db }
```